# Iterate over an array and initialize multiple variables in one line in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to iterate over an array and count the number of positive, negative and zeros in an array. Right now I am doing it like this

```
arr = [1, -1, 0, 2, 3, -2, -5]

pos = arr.select { |i| i > 0 }.count
neg = arr.select { |i| i < 0 }.count
zero = arr.select { |i| i == 0 }.count

puts pos
puts neg
puts zero
```

But is there any way where I can do this in one line? Something like this?

```
pos, neg, zero = arr.select { |i| i > 0; i < 0; i == 0; }.count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `inject` and the `<=>` operator:

```
neg, zero, pos = arr.inject([0,0,0]) { |a,b| a[(b<=>0)+1] += 1; a }
```

---

Alternatively, as @HolgerJust mentioned:

```
neg, zero, pos = arr.each_with_object([0,0,0]) { |a,b| b[(a<=>0)+1] += 1 }
```

is slightly longer but doesn't have the extra `; a` in the block.

---

Inspired by @steenslag's use of `tally`:

```
neg, zero, pos = arr.map { |x| x<=>0 }.tally.values_at(-1,0,1)
```

Comment: You might also use `each_with_object` to avoid the trailing "return value": `neg, zero, pos = arr.each_with_object([0,0,0]) { |resullt, i| result[(i<=>0)+1] += 1 }`

Answer (score 2):

If you use a *counting hash* the code is short and the results are returned in a hash, which may be convenient.

```
arr = [1, -1, 0, 2, 3, -2, -5, 4]
```

You could write

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n<=>0] += 1 }
  #=> {1=>4, -1=>3, 0=>1}
```

or perhaps you would prefer

```
labels = { -1=>:neg, 0=>:zero, 1=>:pos }
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[labels[n<=>0]] += 1 }
  #=> {:pos=>4, :neg=>3, :zero=>1}
```

the last line of which could alternatively be written

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |n,h| h[labels[n<=>0]] = (h[labels[n<=>0]] ||= 0) + 1 }
```

See [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), specifically the (second) form that takes an argument called the *default value* (here zero), and no block. If a hash is defined `h = Hash.new(0)`, then if `h` has no key `k`, `h[k]` returns `0` (and `h` is not changed).

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1, -1, 0, 2, 3, -2, -5]
neg, zero, pos = arr.map{|n| n <=> 0}.tally.values_at(-1, 0, 1)
```

Using the new [tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) method.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, you should just use inject and count using the <=> operator. If you plan to use similar logic frequently, you could monkey patch a #tally_by method into Enumerable like so:

```
class Enumerable
    def my_tally(*keys, &proc)
        proc ||= -> e {e}    # Default identity proc
        h = keys.empty? ? Hash.new(0) : Hash[keys.map{|k|[k, 0]}]
        inject(h){|a, e| a[proc.call(e)] += 1; a}
    end
end
```

This allows you to write:

```
neg, zero, pos = arr.my_tally(-1, 0, 1){|e| e <=> 0}
```

While this is certainly more upfront code than the others, it may be nice to have if you find yourself using similar logic frequently. You could also just make this a regular method somewhere if you don't like monkey-patching.